# background-image doesn't wanna show up on my website

Tags: css

I wanted to set up an image as a transparent background image for my website but anything I try just doesn't wanna work. I've seen on the internet how it works for others, but for me it just doesn't. I converted my image from png to jpeg, but that didn't brought success

Here is my full CSS file

```css
  * {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-size: 120%;
  background: url(DS Organization logo.jpg) 
}

.header {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px auto 0px;
  color: white;
  background: #050505;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000307;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}
form, .content {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: rgb(99, 99, 99);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.input-group {
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.input-group label {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 3px;
}
.input-group input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 93%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background: #050505;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.error {
  width: 92%; 
  margin: 0px auto; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #a94442; 
  color: #a94442; 
  background: #f2dede; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  text-align: left;
}
.success {
  color: #3c763d; 
  background: #dff0d8; 
  border: 1px solid #3c763d;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You need the url to be quoted. Try background: url("DS Organization logo.jpg");

Comment: There's no html or php here, so why the tags?

Comment: Xenvi thank you, that was the problem

Comment: Funk Forty Niner there is html and php, I just uploaded my stylesheet for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url-path` is treated as a string and it needs to be enclosed in quotes. For more information on `url()`, visit [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url())

Comment: Thank you man it worked now, I didn't enclose the url in quotes

Comment: if it helped then accepting the answer would help all of us!

Comment: I just got 1 answer. What do I have to change in my stylesheet to make the background-image transparent?

Comment: you want bg to be transparent or the content? to make content transparent, use ````opacity```` property. read how to use it- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: The content, so that I can see my background image through the content

Comment: The image is now in the top left corner and its small. How do I resize it to make it bigger and to set the same image in the top right corner.                                                               Also I want to put a second image on the bottom left and bottom right corner, how do I do that?

Comment: go and search for it on your search engine. for reference search for "css 'background' property".